# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.Class]

Tags: java, spring

I created a simple web app using hibernate and spring and i want to implement an abstract class that contains the crud operations  but I have this error :

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientService' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'clientDao' while setting bean property 'clientDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'clientDao' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.Class]:
```

GenericDao

```
public interface GenericDao<T, ID extends Serializable> {
    
    T save(T entity);
    T update(T entity);
    void delete(T entity);
    T findById(ID id);
    List<T> findAll();
    void flush();
```

}

GenericDaoImpl

```
@Transactional
public  class GenericDaoImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, ID> {
    
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory ;
    
 private Class<T> persistentClass;
     
     
    
    public GenericDaoImpl() {
    super();
}

    public GenericDaoImpl(Class<T> persistentClass) {
    super();
    this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
}

    @Transactional
    public T save(T entity) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(entity);
        return null;
    }

    @Transactional
    public T update(T entity) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(entity);
        return null;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete(T entity) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
        
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public T findById(ID id) {
        return  (T) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(this.getPersistentClass(), id);
        
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return   this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("* from"+this.getPersistentClass().getSimpleName()).list();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void flush() {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
        
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
        return persistentClass;
    }

    public void setPersistentClass(Class<T> persistentClass) {
        this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
    }
    
    

}
```

ClientDao

```
public interface ClientDao  extends GenericDao<Client,Integer>  {



}
```

ClientDaoImpl

```
@Transactional
@Repository("clientDao")
public class ClientDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<Client,Integer>  implements ClientDao {
    
    
    

    
    
    public ClientDaoImpl(Class<Client> persistentClass) {
        super(persistentClass);
        
    }
```

application context.xml

```
<bean id="client" class="com.webapp.model.Client"/>

  <bean id="genericDao" class="com.webapp.dao.GenericDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="clientDao" class="com.webapp.dao.ClientDaoImpl" parent="genericDao">
    <constructor-arg ref="client" />
   </bean>

 <bean id="clientService" class="com.webapp.service.ClientServiceImpl">
        <property name="clientDao" ref="clientDao" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
<bean id="clientDao" class="com.webapp.dao.ClientDaoImpl" parent="genericDao">
<constructor-arg >com.xxx.Client</constructor-arg >
```

Spring will "cast" the string to the class. Then you can remove the client bean from the XML.

Or remove this parameter from your `ClientDaoImpl`, because it is useless (It can be only this type, so there is no reason to make it a parameter)

```
public ClientDaoImpl() {
    super(com.xxx.Client.class);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> WEB-INF/XXX-XX.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextRepository]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?

Solution is to remove the name property from constructor argument(if it is there). Only keep the reference.
It will work.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor defined in the `ClientDaoImpl` class expects a parameter of type `Class<Client>`. But in the **applicationContext.xml** you set the instance client object to be passed to the constructor.

Change the constructor to receive the object and pass the class to the super, example:

```
public ClientDaoImpl(Client client) {
        super(client.getClass());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Atul. Had I not just had this fix the error message by removing the name property from the servlet context XML file, I would have never guessed this would work. In other words, I went from:

```
 <bean id="myBeanId" class="com.comp.Something">
   <constructor-arg name="userPreference" ref="preferencesDao" />
   <constructor-arg name="user" ref="userDao" />
 </bean>
```

to:

```
<bean id="myBeanId" class="com.comp.Something">
  <constructor-arg ref="preferencesDao" />
  <constructor-arg ref="userDao" />
</bean>.
```

Less *is* more. Also, the error message I got said `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Ambiguous argument values for parameter of type ...` rather than any mention of an "index" value. (That may just be that the message has just changed over time since this question is six years old now). While this is probably obvious when reading carefully, that **number is referring to its index as found in the Java constructor**, not its index in the containing context file's list of constructor-args for that bean. While they often will be ordered the same, they do not have to be. (And after the code has been in production for a while, the context XML and the Java code behind it might suffer some "drift.") That said, the code I just had to change is around 4-5 years old, and this issue just cropped up with a recent build.